# Change DB connection before authenticating user in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to manually authenticate a user in Laravel 5. My application uses 2 databases, which are located on the same server. In my application i already switch connections in the models or query builder, which works perfect.

But now i want to use laravels `Auth::attempt` method to login a user. But the credentials for this user are stored in the second database.

In the user model i have: `protected $connection = 'first_database';`
This is the database it normally should use. But for this 'special' login, i want the user model to use the `second_database`.

Is this possible?

What i tried:

```
     \Config::set('database.default', 'second_database');

    // Login this user while using the second_database
    if(\Auth::attempt(['email'=>\Request::get('email'), 'password'=>\Request::get('password')]))
    {
        dd('Success');
    }
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work.
I`m using **Laravel 5.1**

Comment: If you specify the connection in the model, then that is what Laravel will use.  Your Config::set(...) will make no difference because your model is using first_database, not database.default.  Have you tried removing protected $connection = 'first_database'?

Comment: Removing that is not possible. Because in the rest of the application it needs to use that database (the application uses 3 databases).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can do the following to attempt an authentication:

`$this->guard()->attempt([
     'email' => \Request::get('email'), 
     'password' => \Request::get('password'),
]);`

And in a nutshell, your solution will need to utilize the `guard()` part:

`$this->guard('my-second-database-guard')->attempt([
     'email'=>\Request::get('email'), 
     'password'=>\Request::get('password')
]);`

---

The steps:

If you take a look at `auth.php` you will notice 'provider', and where does provider comes from?

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Provider comes in this section, same `auth.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

So, we could add another User class that utilizes a different connection and use it as a provider for our guard.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'master-users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Master\Models\User::class,
    ],
]
```

And in the guards section:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'master-web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'master-users',
        ],
    ],
```

Of course, we have to duplicate the User class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Master\Models;

use App\Models\User as UserClass;

class User extends UserClass
{
     protected $connection = 'second_database';

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('master-web')
    }
}
```

And then we can attempt to authenticate the users like:

`$this->guard('master-web')->attempt([
     'email' => \Request::get('email'), 
     'password' => \Request::get('password'),
]);`